# Galaxy nexus 4.0.2 gets exception on WebView.onTouchEvent

Tags: android, webview

My ACRA's crush report tells me Galaxy nexus 4.0.2 had exceptions shown below at least 4 times in my app. I suspect user did some multi-touch operation on WebView with landscape orientation (which is known from ACRA's report), but I have no idea why it is causing this.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range   
at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetPointerId(Native Method)   
at android.view.MotionEvent.getPointerId(MotionEvent.java:1927) 
at android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ScaleGestureDetector.java:224)    
at android.webkit.WebView.handleMultiTouchInWebView(WebView.java:6530)  
at android.webkit.WebView$TouchEventQueue.handleQueuedMotionEvent(WebView.java:8088)    
at android.webkit.WebView$TouchEventQueue.enqueueTouchEvent(WebView.java:7986)  
at android.webkit.WebView.onTouchEvent(WebView.java:5963)   
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5486) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1953)    
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1714)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)    
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)    
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)    
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)    
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1892)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1840)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5662)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2863)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can't see anything related to my code from crush report. I use WebView in many places in my app, but not sure where is a problem.

I believe the user is not happy with this and he/she may think my app is poorly designed. Is there anything I can do? Does anyone have this issue? Any info will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue is reported on Android's ITS. WebView related fix will be rolled out in future release. As of now, we have no workaround.

> WebView related issues are fixed.  Don't know about MapView.  Also
>   note that this problem may occur if an application has a touch
>   listener that passes some but not all events down to the
>   ScaleGestureDetector.  It's important that ScaleGestureDetector sees
>   the entire stream of events.
>
> [Issue 18990 - android - unexpected exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range - Android - An Open Handset Alliance Project - Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18990)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hope that user won't think my app is poorly designed, and someday he gets updated release.