# onTouch exception when scrolling multiple WebViews

Tags: android, android-webview, touch-event

I have an app that uses multiple `WebView`s next to each other to display content. When vertically scrolling on one, and I scroll another before the first stops completely I get an exception with the below stack trace. The first line in the stack is the most puzzling to me. I do not know what a `VelocityTracker` is, or what any of the other variables refer to.

```
11-30 10:47:04.740: E/webview(2199): Got null mVelocityTracker when mPreventDefault = 0 mDeferTouchProcess = false mTouchMode = 3
11-30 10:50:23.771: D/AndroidRuntime(2199): Shutting down VM
11-30 10:50:23.771: W/dalvikvm(2199): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at android.webkit.WebView.onTouchEvent(WebView.java:5283)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1702)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2132)
11-30 10:50:23.795: E/AndroidRuntime(2199):     at
...
```

I am using a sub-classed `WebView`, but I do not override the `onTouchEvent()` method.

Interestingly I am only finding this error on the OS v2.3 device I am using as well as any OS v2.x emulator. Anytime I test on a 4.x device everything is fine and all WebViews are able to handle touching and scrolling simultaneously.

What is going on? Is this a known bug in Android? I could not find any record of a similar circumstance. Any suggestions for a workaround? I could just prevent other `WebView`s from being touched so long as one of them is scrolling, but that seems ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how I was causing the problem, but not what the problem truly was.

I stumbled on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570861/galaxy-nexus-4-0-2-gets-exception-on-webview-ontouchevent) which described a problem when a `WebView` does not pass along all `onTouch` events. I had an `onTouchListener` set to my `WebView`s which handled the first `onTouch` event by returning `true` but then passed along subsequent events by returning `false`.

Apparently some versions of the OS get messed up when they aren't able to process all `onTouch` events.